# i am getting errors while trying to use testnet to transfer on block.io

Tags: php

i am having difficulties in sending coin on Block.io API i am using for my app,i am using testnest api, i don't understand the error in anyway and i don't know what to do either. below is the error am getting.[image]

```
$block_io = new BlockIo($apiKey, $pin, $version);


$newAddressInfo = $block_io->get_new_address();

$trans=$block_io->withdraw_from_addresses(array(
'amounts' => '0.005',
'from_addresses'=>'2NBhB9Bm6azwKbpvc1fQvBEFW3JVTAXTT41',
 'to_addresses' => '2NFednEt7ZvAuWVcEXFgWG1t7emrJzQvQoZ'));

echo json_encode($trans);
```

Comment: _“Maximum withdrawable balance is 0.00…”_ sounds like you are trying to spend money you don’t actually have in the sending account.

Comment: i red it online that i don't need to have money in testnet account before i can use it to test run my app,since it is not a production api yet. please enlighten me if i am getting it wrong

Comment: I don’t see how that would make any sense. How would developers be able to properly test such cases, if the API did not behave the same in dev mode, as it would in production? Suggest you go double-check if you actually read that correctly …

Comment: please tutor me on how i can get free testnet coin. Thanks

Comment: Thanks i have found a way out.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Process is right but you are trying to send BTCTEST. Blockio doesn't provide any BTCTEST coin for send or receive. Instead of BTCTEST you can test with LTCTEST and DOGETEST. Blockio provide **500 DOGETEST** and ****0.250** LTCTEST** for testing purpose.

If you have any further question regarding to block.io ask here.

Comment: "Ask here". Where?